# entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile - TestFlight

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, testflight

I am aware that questions have been asked regarding the following error: **entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile**, however, none of the solutions have solved my problem. Here is the situation: I have an app that downloads files, and works great in dev mode. When I TestFlight the app, I get the error below:

```
entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
```

in my console. Even though this error appears, the application runs properly, **EXCEPT** it won't download anything. All of the other functionality works. After the app is downloaded through TestFlight, if I run it and get the above error, if I kill the app and restart it, I don't get the error and the downloads work fine??

Ok here's what I've tried to do to fix it:

1. I deleted all provisioning profiles on developer.apple and on my machine and recreated them. After re-downloading the new provisioning profiles, I tried again - no luck.
2. Next, I added an Entitlements.plist file with the `get-task-allow` set to `false` and set the Entitlements file for Ad Hoc builds. This also did nothing.

Does anyone have an idea?

**Edit:**
Additionally, I have made a new version of the app and copied all of the files over under a new app id, made all new provisioning files, and it still didn't work.

The final thing I tried was making a wildcard ad hoc provisioning profile so that it would sign any app, and I still got the same error.

I really need to figure this out...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the app name, com.whatever.whatever, isn't an exact match with the app name in the provisioning profile.

If that's the problem, you'll need to make them match.  The provisioning profile refers to an app id which has a bundle name.  Your build settings probably has a variable called PRODUCT_NAME.  You can either create a new app id to match your project, or - probably easier - change your project's product name.

Comment: The bundle id and the app id from the provisioning profile are the same. I just confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Danh's answer solved it for me.

I used a provisioning profile with a wildcard app id com.companyName.*, and my bundle identifier for my project was com.companyName.appName.  This would usually not cause any problems, but it seemed to be an issue when implementing entitlements.

Removing 'appName' from my bundle identifier meant that I matched up exactly with my wildcard App ID.

Not sure why there needs to be an exact match for entitlements.

Comment: Hmmm. This didn't solve the problem either. I'm assuming its something caught in xcode or in the app id?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, and I found there are two kinds of profile:

- Ad hoc
- Distribution

I choose the wrong type so I can't install it. You can generate the profile and try again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem — but after updating my Membership subscription.

So you should recreate certs (see more here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3917482).

Thanks,